# Quarkus gradle test fails

Tags: testing, gradle, quarkus

I am trying to run the simple 'getting-started'-type gradle project with quarkus and my unit test fails everytime with this error

```
Caused by: io.quarkus.bootstrap.BootstrapException: Failed to locate project pom.xml for C:\Users\myuser\IdeaProjects\myproj\build\classes\java\main
```

Followed instructions here https://quarkus.io/guides/gradle-tooling
Any suggestions or thoughts on what is going on?

### Gradle version details

### Gradle 5.4

```
Build time:   2019-04-16 02:44:16 UTC
Revision:     a4f3f91a30d4e36d82cc7592c4a0726df52aba0d

Kotlin:       1.3.21
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          11.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.2+9)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Comment: Version `0.14.0` is going to be released soon which I think fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks @geoand. I tried that too today and same behavior.

Comment: Could then open an issue please if there isn't already one?

Comment: Ok I opened one ty @geoand

Comment: Thanks! Just for reference, here is the issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/2307

Answer (score 1):

btw. the problem is still open (current version 0.19.1) and issue (2307) is still unresolved.

The reason is that `@QuarkusTest` points to the `QuarkusTestExtension`, which in `BootstrapClassLoaderFactory.newDeploymentClassLoader` attempts to resolve local project with Maven.

We have options:

- wait for official solution (see issue)
- write own extension overriding `BootstrapClassLoaderFactory` to "understand" gradle project structure
- apply a workaround (for time being), i.e. generate pom.xml from gradle build

#### Workaround

in build.grade:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.quarkus' version '0.19.1'
    // ...
    id 'maven-publish'
}
// ...
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            // augment your pom here if necessary
        }
    }
}
// ...
task createPom(type: Copy) {
    description 'This is workaround to generate pom.xml, needed for @QuarkusTest tests.'
    dependsOn('generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication')
    from "$buildDir/publications/mavenJava/pom-default.xml"
    into '.'
    rename('pom-default.xml', 'pom.xml')
}
```

Note:

- use 'maven-publish', not obsolete 'maven' plugin.
- do not forget to apply `./gradlew createPom` on dependencies changes